# Using multiple models with 1 view in MVC4

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am having trouble trying to combine two models for use with a view. I have created a consolidated model object:

```
Public Class BusinessFormModel
    Public Property busModel As Business
    Public Property busMetaModel As BusinessMeta

    Public Sub New()
         busModel = New Business
         busMetaModel  = New BusinessMeta
    End Sub

End Class
```

For my View I have a form with something like:

```
@ModelType business.BusinessFormModel

@Html.TextBox("business_category", Model.busModel.business_category)
..
@Html.TextBox("business_name", Model.busMetaModel.business_name)
..
@Html.TextBox("business_description", Model.busMetaModel.business_description)
```

My controller looks like this:

```
Function ShowForm() As ActionResult
     Dim model As new BusinessFormModel
     model.busModel.PopulateFromId(2)
     model.busMetaModel.PopulateFromId(2)

     Return View(model)
End Function

Function Submit(ByVal model As BusinessFormModel) As String
     model.busModel.UpdateCategory()
     ...
     model.busMetaModel.UpdateBusinessDescription()
     Return "Submitted"
End Function
```

Basically the ShowForm will populate the object with values from my database based on the id. The id is also a property in this model. Then when the form submits I have functions to update the particular field based on the id. However, seems like when Submit() is called the object that is passed contains `Nothing` values. I should at least be getting data that was bound to the HTML helper controls, right?

I'm not sure if I am doing this right since when I submit the form, the model object that is passed back to the controller does not contain any data. Am I executing the right statements in the view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look into `ViewModel` which will allow you to have multiple models and other business logic in a single view. [ViewModel example exercise](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3fundamentals_topic7.aspx)

Taken as an example. You will have a separate `ViewModel` class that exposes your model(s)  to your view besides your `Controller`.

**ViewModel**

```
Public Class StoreIndexViewModel
    Public Property NumberOfGenres As Integer
    Public Property Genres As List(Of String) 

    Public Property AnotherComplexModel As ComplexModel
End Class
```

**Controller**

```
Public Function Index() As ActionResult
    'Create list of genres
    Dim genres = New List(Of String) From {"Rock", "Jazz", "Country", "Pop", "Disco"}
    'Create your view model
    Dim viewModel = New StoreIndexViewModel With {.NumberOfGenres = genres.Count, .Genres = genres}
    Return View(viewModel) 
End Function
```

In your `View`, you can still refer to you `Model` object the same way but it now contains all the `Models` and other data that now can be used. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Dennis, thanks for your answer. I feel like I am trying this same approach but for some reason when I submit my form to an action in my controller, the passed object contains no values. The data binds correctly initially in the view though.

Comment: Can you post your controller?

Comment: I've edited my original post to contain some of the controller logic.

Comment: It looks fine but the only thing that doesn't sit well with me is that you're instantiating the Models in your BusinessFormModel class.

Comment: From my understanding, when the model is passed to the view, is an entirely new model created?

Comment: Have you tried having the Business and BusinessMeta as parameter for the 'Submit' controller instead of BusinessFormModel then process the data that way?

Comment: Yes, this seems to work fine. It only doesn't work when I use the ViewModel pattern.

Comment: It wouldn't work because the value of the inputs are using the Business and BusinessMeta. The ViewModel is meant for presentational purposes only and the actual model binding needs the actual model themselves.

Comment: Thanks! I was unaware about the binding on submit! It works now!